# How to update NSManagedObject key value pair in a for loop in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi in my application I am using Core Data and at one place I have to update the status (One key in `NSManaged` object). That updation I am doing in a `for` loop. Whenever I am trying to do it app is crashing. Can anyone please help me.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *threadManagedObjectContext = [self myManagedContext] ;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:threadManagedObjectContext] ;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeContextChangesForNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:threadManagedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *object = [threadManagedObjectContext objectWithID:[_object objectID]] ;

 if (statusArray)
 {            
    for (NSDictionary *statusDic in statusArray)
    {        
        [object setValue:[[statusDic allValues] lastObject] forKey:[[statusDic allKeys] lastObject]] ;
     }
  }
```

Here in StatusArray I have a dictionaries. Each dictionary contains one key value pair that will be like this `status:0`

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason:NSDictionary was mutated while being enumerated

Comment: Hi PaulW here is the crash message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0xd01b9e0> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: In case that isn't clear, your code is enumerating an NSMutableDictionary, and it changes the dictionary content within the enumeration block (usually a `for(id key in someDict){}`). It's just not clear given the code you've provided where that enumeration is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [save:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) method on the NSManagedObjectContext to commit the changes you've made.

```
if (statusArray) {
    for (int i=0;i<[statusArray count];i++) {
        NSDictionary *statusDic=[statusArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [object setValue:[[statusDic allValues] lastObject] forKey:[[statusDic allKeys] lastObject]] ;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if(![threadManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving!!!!!: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hemant thanks for your reply. But app is crashing here is the crash message   
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0xd01b9e0> was mutated while being enumerated.' –